# Kprobe on Linux Scheduler and finding linux scheduler

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel

I have two question:
1 - In Fedora source code, where can I find scheduler code?
2 - Can I put Kprobe in Fedora Scheduler? (Or Can I use register_kprobe() in Fedora scheduler?)
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scheduler code could be found under kernel/sched/ directory on latest source code (this is the core file: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/kernel/sched/core.c).

You can insert kprobe hooks almost anywhere in kernel source but not everywhere a list could be found under this list /sys/kernel/debug/kprobes/list (assuming you've a kprobe enabled kernel, and properly mounted).